# how to parse json (from elasticsearch) into array without the meta info

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "contacts",
        "_type": "index",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "c201",
          "name": "Johnny Depp",
          "phone": {
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
            "home": "00 000000"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a elasticsearch json object to use in my application. I do not want to use the elasticsearch api. Also need to strip off the meta info, could you please advise

Comment: And what is the "meta info" in the JSON above? Also, what do you want to do with the JSON once you have "cleaned it up"? And which JSON API do you use?

Comment: I need to use this in my android app, for a start I just need to store  as a key value pair   from the above example I just need `"id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",          ,
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                }
        }`

Comment: Then you just need to get member `"_source"` from the initial JSON Object. I take it you use org.json as bundled by android?

Comment: Also, what if there are several answers? How is the JSON in this case? You could consider using JSON Path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using the [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) package and that the `hits` array only has one element (otherwise you need to loop over `hitsArr`):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject hitsObj = json.getJSONObject("hits");
JSONArray hitsArr = hitsObj.getJSONArray("hits");
JSONObject first = hitsArr.getJSONObject(0); // assumes 1 entry in hits array
JSONObject source = first.getJSONObject("_source");
JSONObject phone = source.getJSONObject("phone");

String id = source.getString("id");
String name = source.getString("name");
String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
String home = phone.getString("home");

System.out.println(id + "\n" + name + "\n" + mobile + "\n" +home);
```